# Starting a new process in a asp.net web service

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-services

I have the following code:

```
 public void BeginConvert(object data)
 {
 ConverterData cObject = (ConverterData)data;
 string argument = string.Format("-i \"{0}\" -b {1} \"{2}\"", cObject.Source,    compression, cObject.Destiny);

 Process converterProcess = new Process();
 converterProcess.StartInfo.FileName = ffPath;
 converterProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;
 converterProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 converterProcess.Start();
 converterProcess.WaitForExit();
 }
```

I use it in a webservice, i start it in a new thread and it return exit code 1 (error, i'm trying to do a video convertion with ffmpeg library), i impersonate ASP.NET to use a local account with permissions to read and write files, when i run it in my machine running or debugging it works but know thta the web service is running in IIS doest'n. Could someone help me?

Comment: There is not problem registered in the event viewer, convertProcess just returned exit code 1 (like i said before) but that doesn't represnt a exception to be logged, i have make some test to see if the application is in the folder when i am calling it and all is ok, like you guys i think must be a problem with permissions, but i impersonate asp.net to use a administration account for test so i assume all its actions are running under that account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can say with almost 100% certainty that this is a permissions issue.  How are you doing the impersonation?  Do you have the same username/password configured on the server?

Another possibility of course is that the target executable in StartInfo.FileName is not in the right place.

Check the Event Viewer for unhandled exceptions and you may get more information.